# PHP preg_replace_callback with unicode

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I wrote a simple script below to simulate my problem.
Both my string and pattern contain unicode characters.

Basically, if I run it from command line (php -f test.php), it prints "match" as expected.
But if I run it through web server (apache, http://localhost/test.php), it prints "no match".
I am using PHP 5.3.

Any idea why it behaves differently?
How do I make it work through web server?

thanks.

```
<?php
function myCallback($matches) {
    return $matches[0];
}

$value = 'aaa äää';
$pattern = '/(\bäää)/u';

$value = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'myCallback', $value, -1, $count);
if ($count > 0) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo 'no match';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you send headers to the server?

Comment: No header. I entered the url to the browser address bar manually. The string is not user input, it's hardcoded in php script.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing default_charset using iniset('default_charset','utf-8').

If it works, it means that CLI and Apache PHP configs have separate php.ini configurations and perhaps this variable is set differently, or maybe based on environment.

You can leave that in as a solution or find an alternative.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: Adding init_set does not help. I am pretty sure they are using the same php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Check your test.php for it to have the correct headers. In PHP you should state:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

As in your HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

As standard it is set to ISO-8895-1 and maybe that is causing the problem. Here you can find some more information about multiple encodings (if utf-8 encoding is not acceptable) and about utf-8 self: http://devlog.info/2008/08/24/php-and-unicode-utf-8/

Comment: The input string does not come from user, it is hardcoded in php. And I am not displaying any unicode in browser. So I am not sure why it has anything to do with headers. But in my response, yes it does have content-type charaset set to 'utf-8'.

Comment: I didn't know, maybe try mb_internal_encoding then

Comment: Also maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063192/preg-replace-and-utf8